# Codeigniter forms won't post

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason I can't get forms to post in Codeigniter 2.1.4, I honestly have no clue where I am going wrong. Can anyone see any obvious problems? No post data is returned  just an empty form the vardump returns (boolean false)

```
public function testpost()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    var_dump($this->input->post());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('testt', 'Test', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo validation_errors();
        echo form_open('test/testpost');
        echo form_input(array('type'=>'text', 'id'=>'testt'));
        echo form_submit(array('value' => 'submit'));
        echo form_close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Very long time I didn't use the Form helper, but I believe it is because in your `echo form_input` you are missing `'name' => 'testt'`. Try with it.

Comment: The form code is there... Also the name doesn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: Can you show the HTML line where you have `<form ...>` ?

Answer (score -1):

You did not create name of text field.

```
echo form_input(array('type'=>'text', 'id'=>'testt', 'name'=>'testt'));
```